# Do set and multiset differ just by a predicate?

Tags: c++, stl

Staring with the following sample code :

```
class cmp
{
    public:
            bool operator()(int a, int b) { return a<=b; }
};

int main()
{
    set<int, cmp> s;
    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(5);
    s.insert(6);
    copy(s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "  "));
    cout<<endl;

    multiset<int> ms;
    ms.insert(2);
    ms.insert(2);
    ms.insert(4);
    ms.insert(5);
    ms.insert(6);
    copy(ms.begin(), ms.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "  "));
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Set - contains unique value.

Multiset - can contain duplicate value.

But in my set implementation, i changed the predicate to accept duplicate values. If we can have this just by changing the predicate, `what's the purpose of having two different containers?` I believe functionality is also same, implementation is also same (Balanced tree). Can somebody elaborate, if i am missing something?

Comment: *But in my set implementation, i changed the predicate to accept duplicate values* -- And how were you able to accomplish this?

Comment: The comparator funciton must follow [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Your comparator function doesn't do that so it will lead to *undefined behavior*. For more information see e.g. [this compare concept reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) and [this `std::set` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i meant, i am passing user-defined predicate "compare" to set, not less<int> or greater<int>.

Comment: @instance -- Then you violated the strict-weak-order, and your `set` is wrong.  You're just lucky your runtime doesn't check for such violation (similar to the debug Visual C++ runtime).

Comment: @instance  I took your code and ran it under Visual Studio.  Lo and behold, I get the "Debug Assertion Failed" dialog with the message "Expression: invalid comparitor".  The runtime does the check by calling your `cmp` function with the parameters in (a,b) order, then calls `cmp` again in (b,a) order, and checks if the return values are the same.  If they are, you lose.

Answer (score 2):

The `Compare` relation must be a ***strict***-weak ordering (in both cases) §23.2.4/2:

> Each associative container is parameterized on `Key` and an ordering relation `Compare` that induces a strict weak ordering (25.4) on elements of `Key`. [...]

And §25.4/4:

> The term strict refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x)` for all `x`), [...]

Your custom `Compare` (`cmp`) fails this requirement, so the behavior of your `std::set<int, cmp>` is not defined.